# Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac34)^n \frac{7n+32}{n(n+2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

> **Question**: Compute $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac34\right)^n \frac{7n+32}{n(n+2)}$$

I first did the partial fraction decomposition into:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac34\right)^n \frac{16}n - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac34\right)^n \frac9{n+2}$$
Here I am stuck because I wrote out a couple terms and I don't see a way that terms can cancel out. Can I get some help?

Comment: Use $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} x^n = \log (1-x)$$

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to cancel terms across both series because of the $(3/4)^n$. Evaluating both series individually (using the Maclaurin series of $\log(1-x)$) gives
$$S=\frac{16}{\log4}-\left(-\frac{33}2+\frac{16}{\log4}\right)=\frac{33}2$$

Comment: Can you elaborate for us how you evaluated those sums?

Comment: @K.defaoite Taylor series expansion of $\log(1-x)$.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $\dfrac{7n+32}{n(n+2)}\cdot\left(\dfrac34\right)^n=f(n)-f(n-2)$

where $f(m)=\dfrac a{m+2}\cdot\left(\dfrac34\right)^m$

so that for $r\ge4,$ $$\sum_{n=2}^r\dfrac{7n+32}{n(n+2)}\cdot\left(\dfrac34\right)^n=\sum_{n=2}^r(f(n)-f(n-2))=f(r)+f(r-1)-f(1)-f(0)$$

$$f(n)-f(n-2)=\left(\dfrac34\right)^n\left(\dfrac a{n+2}-\dfrac an\cdot\dfrac{16}9 \right)$$

We need $\dfrac{7n+32}{n(n+2)}=\dfrac a{n+2}-\dfrac an\cdot\dfrac{16}9=-a\cdot\dfrac{7n+32}{9n(n+2)}\implies a=-9$

Answer (score 0):

In this this type of problems just do telescoping now make the second terms in your partial fraction in powers of n+2 that is just divide and multiply by 16 in second term then do telescoping and possible answers are 33/2